# is there a way to NOT show friends using an app in the auth dialog?

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-authentication

I've created a Facebook app that emphasizes privacy.... is there a way to not show which of your friends are using the app when you approve the permissions?

Comment: do you have examples of what you've tried so far? more details would likely help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not an option of the auth dialog, that's how it looks for all apps.

Users appear there based on their privacy settings, so there may be nobody displayed there even if your friends are using the app already.

If you don't want anything to be displayed there, you could set your app's default privacy setting to 'Only Me' and unless users change that, they won't be elegible to appear there when their friends see the dialog